# What's the different between styles and stylePreprocessorOptions in angular.json in a Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, single-page-application

I'm not sure to understand the difference between **styles** array and **stylePreprocessorOptions > includePaths** array in the angular.json.

can someone enlighten me?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

`styles` : Global styles to be included in the build. So your app will have multi style and you can import to this array so that when angular build your code you will have a global style for whole application

`stylePreprocessorOptions`: Options to pass to style preprocessors. This will allow you to add custom path for scss, sass, or less

You can see the config [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L594)